# Site directory Organizing

Tags: css, xhtml

hi i want to know is there any way to sort folders in website as i want them to be,

i want to sort these in dreamweaver and also on server.
right now my website is not live as it is in development process and it will go live on completion,

also want to tell that majority of my pages are going yo be static.

i know to place a folder on top i can add underscore as prefix but i dont want underscore to display in url so i cannot use it.

is there any way to sort folders manually

Comment: Could you maybe clarify the question a little? You will be able to make any file structure you desire under the site root.

Answer (score 1):

This totally depends on the **developer** and his **point of view**. Do what makes it comfortable to manage and organise the files.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood the question you want to know how to sort your files in folders?
I'll answer with html files as example:

Say you have a folder named "folder" (for simplicity).
In that folder you want to access the html file "page.html".
Then the href link to that page would be (starting from root directory where index is): `folder/page.html`.

If you are linking from inside another folder you use `../folder/page.html`, the dots take you back one step.

You can also define root URL which will be the starting point for all links and then you wont have to go back to root folder.

Hope this was the answer you wanted.

Comment: no no i want to sort folders(directory) not files, right now my folder stucture is sorted by name, i can sort them by date, date modifies, type etc. but i want to sort them, as i want suppose i have 4 folders arranged:- f1 f2 f3 f4, they are sorted by names, now if i want to sort them like say f4 f1 f3 f2 in my site, then how to do it.